# MySQL: Select on GROUP BY only one row with certain criteria

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am having a table with documents where each document has a `doc_id` but on the same `date` for the same `case_id` I might be having two different language versions

```
doc_id      case_id     date        lang
001-89259   1012/02     2008-11-04  FRA
001-144945  10122/04    2014-06-19  ENG
001-57558   10126/82    1988-06-21  ENG
001-62116   10126/82    1988-06-21  FRA
001-91708   10129/04    2009-03-10  FRA
001-116955  10131/11    2013-03-07  FRA
001-102676  10143/07    2011-01-11  FRA
001-104520  10145/07    2011-04-12  FRA
001-72756   10162/02    2006-03-09  FRA
001-72757   10162/02    2006-03-09  ENG
001-82198   10163/02    2007-09-06  ENG
001-57555   10208/82    1988-05-26  ENG
001-62113   10208/82    1988-05-26  FRA
```

What I want to do is to select the english version, if available, per `case_id`, `date`, otherwise keep the french. My output would then look like:

```
doc_id      case_id     date        lang
001-89259   1012/02     2008-11-04  FRA
001-144945  10122/04    2014-06-19  ENG
001-57558   10126/82    1988-06-21  ENG -- keep only the english version
001-91708   10129/04    2009-03-10  FRA
001-116955  10131/11    2013-03-07  FRA
001-102676  10143/07    2011-01-11  FRA
001-104520  10145/07    2011-04-12  FRA
001-72757   10162/02    2006-03-09  ENG -- keep only the english version
001-82198   10163/02    2007-09-06  ENG
001-57555   10208/82    1988-05-26  ENG -- keep only the english version
```

How can I do it with MySQL?

**UPDATE:**

<del>All answers give the correct result but I marked Görkem's as correct as IMO is the most elegant and straight-forward as of why it works.</del>

I initially accepted Görkem's answer but for some reason it returned one wrong result that Strawberry pointed out. That leaves Strawberry's answer as the most elegant and correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(e.doc_id,f.doc_id) doc_id
              , f.case_id
              , f.date
              , COALESCE(e.lang,f.lang) lang 
           FROM my_table f 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table e 
             ON e.case_id = f.case_id 
            AND e.date = f.date 
            AND e.lang = 'ENG';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
        sorted.doc_id,
        sorted.case_id,
        sorted.date,
        sorted.lang
    FROM (
        SELECT
                doc_id,
                case_id,
                date,
                lang
            FROM tbl
            ORDER BY FIELD(lang, 'ENG', 'FRA')
    ) sorted
    GROUP BY sorted.case_id
```

Comment: This *might* work - but relies on an undocumented hack (unless you count the comments section of the manual). I think it might be better to stick with a documented solution.

Comment: Does it work because you sort by language and then `GROUP BY` implicitly picks the first item from the language order?

Answer (score 1):

If this SQL is required for some research, there is a way to get the expected result set:

```
Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(doc_id ORDER BY lang ), ',', 1) doc_id, case_id, date, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(lang ORDER BY lang), ',', 1) lang from table group by case_id,date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  doc_id,
  case_id,
  date,
  lang,
  max(case lang when 'ENG' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY case_id
```